# asp.net-core - Set response's virtual path with middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, virtual-directory, virtual-path

## Setup

- ASP.NET-Core web application hosted at `https://first-domain.com/`
- Using a load-balancer to place the site under `https://second-domain.com/some/path` such that a request to `https://second-domain.com/some/path/Page1` passes the request to `https://first-domain.com/Page1`
- Sending headers when requests are forwarded:

  - `X-Original-Host = 'second-domain.com'`
  - `X-Original-BasePath = 'some/path'`
  - `X-Original-Url = 'https://second-domain.com/some/path/Page1'`
- Pages use the ASP.NET root path character (`~`) to refer to resources relative to the application root.
- Using [ASP.NET-Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to dynamically route the requests based on the headers.

## Problem

My middleware correctly routes the request to the page. Based on the headers, requests to `https://second-domain.com/some/path/PageX` correctly retrieve the resource at `https://first-domain.com/PageX`.

However, `PageX`'s URLs which use the ASP.NET root path character (`~`) are resolving to `/` so then the client tries to access resources at `https://second-domain.com/` which don't exist.

For example, if `PageX.cshtml` had a `<img src="~/myImage.png>` tag, the client's browser will try to retrieve resource `https://second-domain.com/myImage.png` instead of `https://second-domain.com/some/path/myImage.png`

## Question

Is there a way to manipulate the request and/or response with [ASP.NET-Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) such that the ASP.NET root path (`~`) is resolved dynamically?

In other words, I'm trying to set a virtual path dynamically without using infrastructure-defined virtual paths via IIS/Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting [`context.Request.PathBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.pathbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from the middleware.